# Application.yml values not picked when using MockMVC

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

I am using MockMVC to test API calls. The API internally uses some values from the application.yml to get some values. The values for the same are coming as null and I'm getting a NullPointerException. Could you please help me out.

I tried to test another GET call without using MockMVC and it worked completely fine. I cannot use that method as it does not support MultipartFile as a body.

Please find the code below for reference

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyControllerTest {

    private String token = null;
    private String url=null;
    MockMvc mockMvc;
    public CceControllerTest() {
        GenerateTokenTest generateToken = new GenerateTokenTest();
        try {
            this.url = TestingConstant.ip +TestingConstant.port + "cce";
            this.token=generateToken.getToken();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    
     @Before
        public void before() {
            MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new MyController()).build();
        }
     
   
    @Test
    public void getdata() {
        try {
            String u = this.url + "/getdata";
            
            mockMvc.perform(
                    MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(u).header("Authorization", "Bearer" + token))
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
            
            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    @Test
    public void excelImportNew() {
        try {
            String apiUrl = this.url + "/excelImportNew";
            MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", "test.csv", "text/csv", "CSV content".getBytes());
            String State = "Himachal Pradesh";
            String District = "Hamirpur";
            String userName = "abcd";
            mockMvc.perform(
                    MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart(apiUrl).file(file).header("Authorization", "Bearer" + token)
                            .param("State", State).param("District", District).param("userName", userName))
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().string("File uploaded successfully"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
     
    
}
```

Could you please provide your suggestions

Thanks in advance :)

Tried using webAppContextSetup() by autowiring the WebAppContext but that is throwing a NullValueException saying that no WebAppContext found.

Comment: Remove the `@Before` method. Remove `@SpringBootTest`. Add `@Autowired` to `MockMvc` field. Re-run test. You shouldn't need `@ExtendWith` and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` as that is already part of `@WebMvcTest`.

Comment: @M.Deinum, upon doing the above getting the below exception

Cannot invoke "org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(org.springframework.test.web.servlet.RequestBuilder)" because "this.mockMvc" is null

Comment: You did add `@Autowired` on the `MockMvc` field?

Comment: @M.Deinum yes I did

Comment: Make sure you are using the `@Test` from JUnit5 and not JUnit4. Judging from the `@Before` you are mixing JUnit4 and JUnit5.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried using junit4 and junit5

Comment: Don't mix, make sure you are using the imports from junit5.

Comment: @M.Deinum could u please provide a snapshot of ur code so that i could refer and I am using junit4

Comment: Don't use Junit4 use Junit5 as that comes with Spring Boot by default. Change the imports for the `@Test` annotation and it will work.